# links aren't working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, http-status-code-404

My links in my navigation aren't working on my wordpress site. All I did was upload a custom template, not every link goes to a 404. It doesn't make sense. I've checked the .htaccess file and it doesn't indicate that it's doing anything wrong. This is the URL http://www.winecountryclassicboats.com/ Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What are your permalink settings ? Also, what is your homeurl and blogurl values ??

Comment: I clicked a number of your links and didn't find any 404s.